# Bosch security camera pinout

Tags: ethernet, camera, pinout

I have a Bosch NDC-274-PT security camera that had the wiring cut off at the base.

It's a POE security camera (though it also supports regular 12 or 24V power), so I was hoping to find typical ethernet wiring inside.  No such luck.

Instead I've got two connectors.  On the first:

- Grey - seems to connect to pins 1 and 6 of the coilcraft transformer
- Purple
- Blue
- Green - seems to connect to pins 4 through 5 of the coilcraft transformer

And on the second:

- Brown
- Black (no continuity with the other ground wire)
- Orange
- Black - Ground, connects to the cable shielding and ground lug
- Yellow
- Red

I'm hoping there weren't any necessary electronics in the cable/plug itself.

Anybody know what wires would match up with a typical ethernet jack?  Or is there any way to determine that myself with a multimeter?  Unfortunately I do not have the other end of the cable, or mapping it out would be easy.

Close up of the connectors:
[image: Close up of connectors]

Whole board:
[image: board]

Comment: found this ... http://resource.boschsecurity.com/documents/MIC_Cables_Data_sheet_enUS_9930235019.pdf

Comment: @jsotola thanks, but unfortunately that cable is for a different series of camera (older analog ones by the looks of it).

Comment: Find the Ethernet magnetics and trace the connections to that?  Seems like the interesting parts are on the other side of the board.  Usage / repair questions aren't really on topic here - questions here should be answerable based on documented facts, questions where what you are seeking is input from someone who has the same product don't really fit the mission of this site.

Comment: contact bosch tech support

Comment: here is the datasheet for the poe transformer ... https://www.coilcraft.com/poe_min.cfm

Comment: Picture of other side of PCB would inspire people more.  The two camera connector options make the likelihood of ANY electronics in the cable VERY LOW.  Locate the Ethernet magnetics and see which pins they go to.  You should find two pairs with transformed across them and then the power electronics between the pairs.  The 4 wire connector looks like connected to PSU components probably the 12-24V DC input perhaps using the Coilcraft for common mode choke or as flyback transformer but active component is out of sight.

Answer (score 3):

The magnetics (ethernet transformers) for the ethernet socket aren't on the board, so they must have been on the other end of that wire.

You'll need to find the ethernet chip (possibly on the other side of the board) and trace the connections from that to the socket and compare against what you find in the data-sheet for that part to see what's missing.

The first connector is probably POE on the ethernet transformers, the second data lines to the ethernet transformers.